# Pagination Not Displaying

Tags: php, javascript, css, pagination

I am a front-end designer/code trying to style up pagination for a web app.  It is called in one section of the application and called it with the following:

```
<?php echo $pagination;?>
```

And I used CSS + the Pagination JS file to style it up.

In another section of the application, which I have just been asked to style, it is called with this:

```
<?php echo $pages;?>
```

And looks entirely unstyled.  When I replace `$pages` with `$pagination` the page control no longer appears.  When I run a search for `$pages` through our repository I see no matches for `$pages` (not even in the pagination file).

Anyone have any idea why pagination breaks the control?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I did a really bad job of explaining this.  The problem is that I can find a reference to the variable `$paginate` in the repository (in paginate.js) and I was able to assign a CSS class to it through that JavaScript file, but I can't find any references to `$pages`, which I just can't wrap my head around.  If I change the variable to something else that I think is defined (such as `$paginate`) it no longer displays the pagination.

**EDIT**: Figured it out, it was in the controller in CodeIgniter.

Comment: You know, there is not only *the one* pagination script. How can we know without knowing the pagination is created, what the context of the code is etc. In it's current form, the question is impossible to answer and I doubt that it will be answerable. You should talk with those who are responsible for this.

Comment: SO what's the content of the vars? If one appears unstyled, then your css descriptors and whatnot don't match whatever that version of the control is using. How about providing some more info beyond "It's broken, fix it"?

Comment: Sorry about that, that's the weird thing while $paginate points to Paginate.js file where I defined the css class (.pagination-results-blue) I can't find anything that references $page - so I can't define a CSS class to it.

Comment: cant you just view source to see what class(s) are applied to the text in question, and adjust the css, this is really nothing to do with php

Comment: You should have added better tags like "codeigniter" so that it would be more related to this topic.

Comment: @Walker: If you've solved the problem, write it in an answer on this page and mark it as accepted - that'll stop it showing up in the unanswered questions list (and might help others who have the same question). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not quite sure if I my answer will help, but as far as I undertood your question

1. When $pages is called, in the source don't you see the HTML tags that those pages are? Why don't you try not assign smth in javascript but make styles in your CSS according to those html tags that are generated?

for ex.

```
<div class="smth">
    <div class="your_$page_div">
         <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            etc...
```

In your CSS do smth like div.smth div.your_$page_div ul li {some stile} 
so you won't have to replace anything and assign smth in core file.

I hope I correctly understood what you were asking :P Cheers!

I just saw you figured out the problem